# Using PruneCluster with AngularJS Leaflet Directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, leaflet, angular-leaflet-directive

I am having problems loading clustered markers for geojson data using PruneCluster. The clusters are not displayed and there are no errors in the console to help in trouble shooting. Here is my current controller.js code:

```
 angular.module('bizvizmap').controller('controller', [
    '$scope', '$http', '$filter', 'leafletData',
    function ($scope, $http, $filter, leafletData){
    $scope.center = {
        lat: 39.5500507,
        lng: -105.7820674,
        zoom: 4
            },
    $scope.defaults = {
        scrollWheelZoom: false
            },
    $scope.events = {
            map: {
            enable: ['zoomstart', 'drag', 'click', 'mousemove'],
            logic: 'emit'
            }
            },
    $scope.layers = {
            baselayers: {
            osm: {
            name: 'OpenStreetMap',
            url: 'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
            type: 'xyz'
                    }
                },
            markers:{}
    },

    $scope.map = null;
    leafletData.getMap("bizvizmap").then(function(map){
        $scope.map = map;
    });
    function renderMarkers(data, map){
        var markerLayer = new PruneClusterForLeaflet();
        for (var i=0; i < data.length; i++){
            var marker = new PruneCluster.Marker(data[i].geometry.coordinates[1], data[i].geometry.coordinates[0]);
            markerLayer.RegisterMarker(marker);
        }
        map.addLayer(markerLayer);
        markerLayer.ProcessView();
    }
    $scope.geojson = {};
    $http.get('data/bizvizmap.geojson').success(function (data){
            $scope.data = data;
            // Render clustered markers
            renderMarkers(data, $scope.map);
        });
]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with my code was that it was not accessing the features in the GeoJson file and the clustered markers could not be displayed. I solved the issue as follows:

```
 function renderMarkers(data, map){
        var markerLayer = new PruneClusterForLeaflet();
        for (var i=0; i < data.length; i++){
            var marker = new PruneCluster.Marker(data[i].geometry.coordinates[1], data[i].geometry.coordinates[0]);
            markerLayer.RegisterMarker(marker);
        }
        map.addLayer(markerLayer);
        markerLayer.ProcessView();
    }
    $scope.geojson = {};
    $http.get('data/bizvizmap_final.geojson').success(function (data){
            $scope.data = data;
            // Render clustered markers
            renderMarkers(data.features, $scope.map);
        });
```